# Python TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'unicode'

Tags: python, django, unicode, typeerror

I'm working on a django field validation and I can't figure out why I'm getting a type error for this section:

```
def clean_tid(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['tid']
    stdout_handel = os.popen("/var/www/nsmweb/jre1.6.0_14/bin/java -jar /var/www/nsmweb/sla.jar -t %s grep -v DAN")  % data
    result = stdout_handel.read()
```

Do I have to convert data somehow before I can pass it in as a string variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your parenthesis.

Wrong

```
stdout_handel = os.popen("/var/www/nsmweb/jre1.6.0_14/bin/java -jar /var/www/nsmweb/sla.jar -t %s grep -v DAN")  % data
```

Might be right.

```
stdout_handel = os.popen("/var/www/nsmweb/jre1.6.0_14/bin/java -jar /var/www/nsmweb/sla.jar -t %s grep -v DAN"  % data )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small tip - it's better to use `subprocess` module and `Popen` class instead of `os.popen` function. More details [here (docs)](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).